# Из номеров 000 001 ... 999 999 нужно найти все счастливые билеты (как сделать с помощью разбивания на масив char )

Tags: java

```
public class LuckyNumber {    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 000001; i <= 999999; i++){
            int number1 = i/100000;
            int number2 = (i/10000)%10;
            int number3 = (i/1000)%10;
            int number4 = (i/100)%10;
            int number5 = (i/10)%10;
            int number6 = i%10;

            if(number1 + number2 + number3 == number4 + number5 + number6){
                sum++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("There are " + sum + " lucky numbers");
    }
}
```

Comment: А что, по-вашему, тут неграмотно? Чем плох?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский здесь просто проверяется счастливый билет или нет. А мне нужно найти все счастливые билеты. Счастливый билет - это когда сумма первых трех цифр в номере билета равна сумме второй тройки цифр (номер шестизначный). 

000 001
...
999 999

Comment: Думаю вам стоит в вопросе об этом написать, что  из указанных шести номеров нужно составить все возможные комбинации счастливых билетов

Comment: Обновила. Такой вариант подходит? С целочисленным делением и остатком от деления.

Comment: Нужно только подсчитать количество счастливых билетов? Показывать каждый номер не обязательно?

Comment: @Sergiks давайте покажем. Я просто сумму подсчитала.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class LuckyNumber {
public static void main(String[] args){
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 000001; i <= 999999; i++){
    int number1 = i/100000;
    int number2 = (i/10000)%10;
    int number3 = (i/1000)%10;
    int number4 = (i/100)%10;
    int number5 = (i/10)%10;
    int number6 = i%10;

    if(number1 + number2 + number3 == number4 + number5 + number6){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}    
}
```

не подходит?

Comment: А может, с рекурсией, таблицей из 18 вариантов суммы?..

Comment: @Sergiks, я хочу в стрингу конвертнуть, дальше разбить на массив и по элементам сумировать и сравнить левую часть (сумма трех чисел) с правой частью(сумма трех чисел)

Comment: @Red Shaman, подходит). я уже правки внесла.)

Answer (score 3):

Можно меньше итераций делать.

Сумм мало: от 1 до 18. Достаточно пробежать от 1 до 999 и сохранять очередное число в массив, в зависимости от суммы его цифр. Каждой сумме соответствует массив тех чисел, из которых она получается.

Напр. для суммы 1 это будет массив из 1, 10 и 100.

Далее остаётся составить все возможные пары из каждого массива:

```
001 001
001 010
001 100
010 001
010 010
010 100
100 001
100 010
100 100
```

Так не будет «холостых» вариантов в циклах. У меня получился **55251** счастливый билет. 999+55251=56250 итераций вместо 999999. А вероятность получить счастливый билет, выходит, чуть больше 1/20.

Вывод всех счастливых билетов на JavaScript:

```js
var sums = {}, i, n, s, count = 0, html = '', out = document.getElementById('out');
for(i=1; i<=999; i++) {
  s = 0; n = i;
  while(n > 0) {
    s += n%10;
    n = Math.floor(n/10);
  }
  if( sums[s]) sums[s].push(i);
  else sums[s] = [i];
}

for(s in sums) {
  html += "<h4>Sum = " + s + "</h4>\n";
  for(i=0; i<sums[s].length; i++) {
    for(n=0; n<sums[s].length; n++) {
      count++;
      html += ('000' + sums[s][i]).slice(-3) + ('000' + sums[s][n]).slice(-3) + " ";
    }
  }
}

html = "<h3>" + count + " счастливых билетов</h3>\n" + html;
out.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<link href="https://yastatic.net/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="out"></div>
```